# PHP Как выполнить команду в консоли?

Tags: php, linux, debian

есть такой код `exec("echo 'test' > /dev/pts/0");` (он отправляет сообщение администратору сервера в консоль) но когда я ввожу message.php в браузере в консоли ssh ничего не происходит, сообщения нет

Comment: зайдите на сервер и нажмите "w" скорее всего у вас другая консоль : "/dev/pts/1"

Comment: нет всё правильно

Comment: я захожу простым юзером и нажимаю "watch /dev/pts/0" получаю ответку : "/dev/pts/0: Permission denied" Попробуйте своим мощным юзером подсмотреть консоль №0.

Comment: Я под root сижу и у меня тоже самое

Comment: значит уже надо разрешить PHP запускать команды. *по-умолчанию нельзя* полазить в настройках придётся.

Comment: `/etc/php/7.2/apache2$ cat php.ini | grep disable` почитать `disable_functions = ..` может там `exec` и находится.

Comment: disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_get_handler,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,pcntl_async_signals,pcntl_unshare,

Comment: отключено только `pcntl_exec`, не знаю, может посмотреть в `/var/log/apache2/error.log` - что-нибудь скажет?